# What repo is responsible for writing this error message?

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, repository

I was wondering what repo is responsible for writing this error message, because I'd like to make a PR to modify it. I cloned the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and [babel](https://github.com/babel/babel) repos, but vscode's find function didn't return a result for the error message.

The error message is this:

> One of your dependencies, babel-preset-react-app, is importing the
> "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" package without
> declaring it in its dependencies. This is currently working because
> "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" is already in your
> node_modules folder for unrelated reasons, but it may break at any
> time.
>
> babel-preset-react-app is part of the create-react-app project, which
> is not maintianed anymore. It is thus unlikely that this bug will ever
> be fixed. Add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object" to
> your devDependencies to work around this error. This will make this
> message go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone somehow ends up here, I found the [repo](https://github.com/babel/babel-plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object). It is from the babel org, but not in their main repo.